# Calculation on consecutive array elements

Tags: scala

I have this:

```
val myInput:ArrayBuffer[(String,String)] = ArrayBuffer(
    (a,timestampAStr),
    (b,timestampBStr),
    ...
)
```

I would like to calculate the duration between each two consecutive timestamps from `myInput` and retrieve those like the following:

```
val myOutput = ArrayBuffer(
    (a,durationFromTimestampAToTimestampB),
    (b,durationFromTimestampBToTimestampC),
    ...
)
```

This is a paired evaluation, which led me to think something with `foldLeft()` might do the trick, but after giving this a little more thought, I could not come up with a solution.

I have already put something together with some `for loops` and `.indices`, but this does not seem as clean and concise as it could be. I would appreciate if somebody had a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `sliding` to achieve what you want. For example, if you have a collection

```
scala> List(2,3,5,7,11)
res8: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
```

The list of differences is `res8.sliding(2).map{case List(fst,snd)=>snd-fst}.toList`, which you can zip with the original list.

```
scala> res8.zip(res8.sliding(2).map{case List(fst,snd)=>snd-fst}.toList)
res13: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (3,2), (5,2), (7,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` your array with itself, after dropping the first item - to match each item with the consecutive one - and then map to the calculated result:

```
val myInput:ArrayBuffer[(String,String)] = ArrayBuffer(
  ("a","1000"),
  ("b","1500"),
  ("c","2500")
)

val result: ArrayBuffer[(String, Int)] = myInput.zip(myInput.drop(1)).map {
  case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (k1, v2.toInt - v1.toInt)
}
result.foreach(println)
// prints:
// (a,500)
// (b,1000)
```